# В чем уязвимость файлов install.php и upgrade.php?

Tags: wordpress, защита, уязвимости

Столкнулся с пентестом, многие говорят что надо удалять эти файлы в `WordPress`, но какая в них уязвимость-то?

Для справки, я файлы ядра не удаляю, с функционалом ВП знаком.

Comment: Наверное, чтобы никто не перешёл по `yoursite.com/install.php` и не переустановил движок, нет?

Comment: @Jagailo переустановить движок снаружи невозможно.

Comment: Не слушай такую ересь. Файлы ядра вообще никогда не трогай.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да никакой в них уязвимости нет. В WordPress вообще нет известных уязвимостей. И все подобные советы - это из серии monkey business. Если заняться нечем, то можно придумать себе работу - удалять какие-то файлы, скрывать версию WordPress (которая определяется с помощью 10 различных способов). Не хочется тут разводить холивар, но и игнорировать массу вредных советов не где-нибудь, а на Stack Overflow тоже не хочется.

Почитайте блог компании WordFence - ведущего мирового эксперта по вопросам безопасности WordPress. Про xml-rpc они [написали еще в 2015 году](https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2015/10/should-you-disable-xml-rpc-on-wordpress/). А уж там люди разбираются в вопросах безопасности получше нас с вами.

Все эти брутфорс-атаки эффективно закрываются установкой простеньких плагинов, блокирующих IP, или того же WordFence.

Советы по защите файлов .php от доступа представляются более чем странными - это как, интересно, снаружи можно прочитать содержимое wp-config.php???

Советы по удалению неиспользуемых файлов в WordPress - тоже безусловно вредные. Потому что после обновления вам придётся повторять этот мартышкин труд.

А вот обновлять ядро и плагины - критически важно, потому что иногда все-таки обнаруживаются уязвимости, и команда WordPress оперативно выпускает обновления безопасности.

Лучше потратьте свое время на то, чтобы ваш код в WordPress не зависел от обновлений - т.е. был вынесен в дочернюю тему или плагины, не использовал устаревших (deprecated) функций, был хорошо документирован и легко поддавался модификации.

Comment: Кто минусует? Мнение написано весьма толковое. Вордпресс необоснованно считают дырявым решетом, но на 99% это по причине дырявости плагинов, которые написаны неизвестно кем и неизвестно как. А бесконтрольная установка плагинов после того, как удалят "дырявые" файлы upgrade.php -- это называется "театр безопасности". Хотелось бы послушать обоснования минусующих -- желательно отдельным ответом.

Comment: @AK да те и минусуют, кто в плену расхожих представлений о WP ))) Считают себя умнее команды, которая поддерживает движок для 25% сайтов в Интернете ))

Comment: Я плюсанул, ответ толковый, но по поводу того, что в WP нет известных уязвимостей - это сомнительно. Как насчет REST API от WP?

Comment: @Klimenkomud в REST API тоже нет известных уязвимостей. Почитайте про последние обновления безопасности. В основном закрывают мелочи весьма своеобразного характера.

Comment: @KAGGDesign у вас кстати верстка на сайте едет =(

Comment: @LexHobbit да и фиг с ним. Там ошибки в Curvy Slider, надо его заменить. Главное, что на клиентских сайтах верстка не едет )

Comment: @Klimenkomud кстати вот тоже интересный случай, относящийся к вопросу описанный на том же [wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2017/07/wpsetup-attack/)

Comment: @Klimenkomud так что считаю свой ответ тоже верным, так как он подкреплен реальными фактами, проверенными не только мной, но и еще множеством других pentest специалистами

Comment: @KAGGDeeign, спасибо за луч здравого смысла

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko ха-ха, луч света в темном царстве )) да не за что, на самом деле. На SO как раз превалируют здравые суждения.

Comment: @KAGGDesign `На SO как раз превалируют здравые суждения` - еле сдержал смех))

Comment: Вопрос: если никаких уязвимостей не известно, чего мне вордпрес недавно на сайте клиента сделал принудительное обновление и выслал уведомление на почту?

Comment: @larrymacbarry а почему Windows и MacOS постоянно получают обновления безопасности?

Comment: Принудительное обновление при выключенных обновлениях у меня впервые. Из-за этого даже старый плагин слетел. Я делаю вывод, что дырку закрывали

Comment: @larrymacbarry обратите внимание на второе предложение: "известных уязвимостей". Периодически дырки обнаруживают везде. И когда говорят нет "известных уязвимостей", это означает, что нет неустранённых уязвимостей на сегодняшний день. Что касается принудительного обновления, скорее всего, речь об этом: https://wordpress.org/news/2017/01/wordpress-4-7-1-security-and-maintenance-release/ Там было больше шума с PHPMailer, на WP не влияло, но на всякий случай решили закрыть.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Холивара не хотелось, но как понеслась, люди уже толком на вопрос не смотрят, да и на то, что ответ уже есть =)

Comment: @Klimenkomud вопрос сам по себе холиварный )) . Но в ответе SeVlad есть рациональное зерно (назначение файлов и последствия удаления), поэтому я плюсанул. Насчет удаления файлов - это он обращался к другому отвечающему.

Answer (score -1):

> многие говорят что надо удалять эти файлы

*Говорят, что кур доят..*
А по названию `upgrade.php` неужто неясно, что файл нужен для обновлений?   А `install.php` нужен и для установки плагинов и тем и для обновлений. И вообще он встречается в многих файлах дистрибутива. Стоит подумать что будет если он вдруг не найдётся.

Файлы ядра трогать нельзя, если нет стойкого желания поломать сайт и наплодить дыр. Никакие нельзя. Если нужно изменить функционал, то это делается другими способами, а не удалением файлов.

Comment: Спасибо конечно за пояснение что и для чего нужно, но и без вас знаю зачем эти файлы нужны. Ответ ваш абсолютно не по теме.

Comment: И честно говоря, не вижу в теле своего вопроса даже малейшего намека на удаление этих файлов. Многие достаточно авторитетные (с моей точки зрения) ресурсы утверждают, что эти файлы -потенциальный бекдор, но в чем их уязвимость -  нигде не нашел. Ваш же ответ касается вопроса как юному "защитнику" сайта не наломать дров. Надеюсь понятно почему ваш ответ я посчитал не по теме

Comment: Не видишь в своём вопросе про [удаление](http://i.imgur.com/sz2Y8TW.jpg)? вот это номер!!! Ну извини что хотел помочь. А. да не те у тебя авторитеты.вот даже рассказывают что про уязвимости а какие именно не рассказывают. Еще раз извини, больше такого не повтриться.

Comment: Да, про удаление совсем не было. Ну ты и .. жук. http://i.imgur.com/xRXB8Yj.jpg